# How to filtered data from syncfusion_flutter_datagrid in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

`SfDataGrid(allowFiltering: true,allowSorting: true,source: tableInfoDataSource,defaultColumnWidth: 100,columnWidthMode: context.responsiveValue(desktop: ColumnWidthMode.fill,mobile: ColumnWidthMode.fitByColumnName),columns: modelService.billList.isNotEmpty ? columns : []),`
I enabled filter option. Now, If I filter by using default option on screen. Then how to I get that filtered data

Comment: Be aware that the SyncFusion products in the Dart/Flutter pub are *not* open source.  They are released under a commercial license that may subject you or your organization to a financial liability, and will affect downstream re-users of your code.

Comment: Oh ok brother. Thank you for your information. What is the alternative in flutter

Comment: I applied the Community License

Comment: Which is ok for you personally, but does not qualify if you get four other collaborators, or let you publish your code as open source, without requiring all downstream users to also qualify for and obtain a community license.  It's viral.

Comment: Ok brother. Thank you, I will try any alternative packages.